# Unable to print success message on the HTML page using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I created a a contact form through which I'm going to post this data and return the success message. I'm able to successfully post the data but not able to display the success or failure message on the form.
Below is my code :
**Contact.php** :

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=chop($_POST['element_4_1']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_2']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_3']);
$email=chop($_POST['email']);
$message1=chop($_POST['input4']);

if ($name && $phone && $email) { 

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: sales@test.in \n";
$recipient= "test@test.in";



$subject="Online Enquiry  ";


$message.="\nName                   : $name\n";

 $message.="\nPhone                  : $phone\n";

 $message.="\nEmail ID               : $email\n";

 $message.="\nMessage                : $message1\n";


 //send auto-reply
$subject_reply="Thank you for contacting Rugs of India";
$message_reply="Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.";
mail($email, $subject_reply, $message_reply, $headers);



 //Send Mail
//===========
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo $message_reply;
} else {
echo "There was an error. Please try again.";
} 
}

?>
```

**Contactus.html**

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" /> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /> 
        <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/coder.css"/>
        <style  type="text/css">
.bg-color{
background-color:#F9F1E4;
border-radius:5px;
margin:5px;
}
.row_color{
border:2px solid #A40F17;
margin:0px;
}
.footer_class{
background-color:#A40F17;
height:40px;
}
.font_color{
color:#fff;
margin-top:5px;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #A40F17;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.h_color{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.danger{
color:#A40F17;
}
.h_top{
margin-top:30px;
}
.h_height{

height:173px;
}


input.text:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9 !important;

  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
} 
input.text:required {
box-shadow: none; /* Firefox (tested v6) adds red shadow by default */
}


</style>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log( "ready!" );
  $("#button").click(function(){
console.log("ready2");

                  $.ajax({

                    url: './contact.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "name": $("#name").val(),
                        "element_4_1": $("#element_4_1").val(),
                        "element_4_2": $("#element_4_2").val(),
                        "element_4_3": $("#element_4_3").val(),
                        "email": $("#email").val(),
                        "input4": $("#input4").val(),

                    },                    
                   success: function(data){
                    $("#stage").text(data);

                    }

                });
  });
});
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
    <div class="row h_color h_height">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeader">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeader">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#fff;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
<div id="stage">

   </div>
                    <h3>Contact Us</h3>

                    <div class="col-lg-7 well">
<form class="contact-form">


                        <h4 style="padding-top:8px;">Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked <font color="red">*</font></h4>
                            <label>Name<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
                            <input class="form-control" style="height:35px;width:230px;border-radius:4px;" required type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br>
                            <label>Phone<font color="red">*</font></label><br>


        <span>

            <input id="element_4_1" name="element_4_1" class="element text" size="3" maxlength="3" value=""  type="text"> -

        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_4_2" name="element_4_2" class="element text" size="4" maxlength="4" value="" type="text"> -

        </span>
        <span>
            <input id="element_4_3" name="element_4_3" class="element text" size="10" maxlength="10" value=""  type="text" required >

        </span>

<br><br>
                            <label>Email<font color="red">*</font></label><br>
                            <input id="email" class="form-control" style="height:35px;width:230px;border-radius:4px;" required type="email" name="text"/><br>
                            <label for="input4">Message</label>
                            <textarea name="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="4" id="input4"></textarea>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <button type="submit" style="margin-left:65px;"class="btn btn-large btn-info" id="button">Submit</button>
</form>

                    </div>


            </div>



        </div>
    </div>  
    <footer>
    <div class="row footer_class">
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I submit the form, the page gets refreshed without showing the success message.How can I correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're setting your AJAX success callback to $("#stage").text(data); but you have no DIV with the ID stage. Add

```
<div id="stage"></div>
```

where you want the message to appear.

Comment: Change "$("#stage").text(data);" to "$("#stage").text(data);alert(data);"  Do you get a message box with the expected message?

Comment: I don't see any alert box

Comment: Success is never getting triggered then. Can you open the browser console (F12) and go to Console and go through the process to see if any errors come up?

Comment: With firebug Can I see

Comment: You should be able to. Do you see any JS errors when running through the process?

Comment: Yes...SyntaxError: illegal character  

`"$("#stage").text(data);alert(data);"`

Comment: I just noticed you have two versions of jQuery on your page. Remove         <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">

Does that change anything?

Comment: I see illegal character at #stage

Comment: Do u think I have to change Jquery

Comment: You don't need to change jQuery, but you're calling it twice with two different versions. Not sure if that's the problem, but you definitely need to remove one of them.

Comment: are you positive contact.php is returning something?  try to do echo "hello" on that page and see what result you get.  also, try $('#stage').html(data);  it shouldn't matter but you never know.

Answer (score 0):

There was a small mistake in your code. I did the rectification...

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=chop($_POST['element_4_1']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_2']);
$phone.=chop($_POST['element_4_3']);
$email=chop($_POST['email']);
$message1=chop($_POST['input4']);


if ($name && $phone && $email) { 

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: sales@test.in \n";
$recipient= "test@test.in";



$subject="Online Enquiry  ";


$message ="\nName                   : $name\n";

 $message.="\nPhone                  : $phone\n";

 $message.="\nEmail ID               : $email\n";

 $message.="\nMessage                : $message1\n";


 //send auto-reply
$subject_reply="Thank you for contacting Rugs of India";
$message_reply="Thank you for contacting us. We will get back to you shortly.";
mail($email, $subject_reply, $message_reply, $headers);



 //Send Mail
//===========
if(mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo $message_reply;
} else {
  echo "There was an error. Please try again.";
} 
}

?>
```

error was in the $message variable. It was not defined.

and one more thing your form click executes breaking your validation. It is not validating your form. Please make your validation correct. You can replace the above code.

Made some changes in your script...

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    console.log( "ready!" );
     $("#button").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log("ready2");

                  $.ajax({

                    url: './contact.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "name": $("#name").val(),
                        "element_4_1": $("#element_4_1").val(),
                        "element_4_2": $("#element_4_2").val(),
                        "element_4_3": $("#element_4_3").val(),
                        "email": $("#email").val(),
                        "input4": $("#input4").val(),

                    },                    
                   success: function(data){
                    $("#stage").text(data);

                    }

                });
  });
});
</script>
```